# Casting two different object arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

I have two object arrays. One's implicitly casted by covariance from A[] to object[] and then explicitly casted back without problem. The other is an object list that I add some A's to and make an object[] from which I try to cast to A[].

```
public class A {}

object[] o = new A[]{new A(), new A()};
A[] a_2 = (A[])o;

List<object> lo = new List<object>();
lo.Add(new A());
lo.Add(new A());
A[] a_1 = (A[])lo.ToArray();
```

The second test fails with `System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.` I can kind of see how this might raise an exception as we could have added anything to the object list whereas with the implicit cast, the original array must have been all As.

Is there any way to complete the second cast if the list has all As if A is not known at compile-time? Why does the second one throw the exception as, on the surface, they are both just object[] to A[] casts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to complete the second cast. Array variance depends on the actual type of the array object itself, not its contents. You can cast `A[]` to `object[]` array because of the array type. Note that if you try to add non-`A` objects to the `A[]` cast as `object[]`, that still fails at run-time because the array is still an `A[]`.

If you want an `A[]` object when all you have is an `object[]` object, you will need to create the new `A[]` object and copy the values from the original array to the new one.

Comment: So it stores internally whether it is an A[] after you cast it to an object[]?

Comment: Yes, the cast is simply a reinterpretation, not a conversion. In fact, in your example, the array `o` is in fact referencing the same object as originally created and as subsequently referenced by `a_2`. I.e. `object.ReferenceEquals(o, a_2)` returns `true`. In other words, this isn't just an "internal" thing...all the cast does is change how your code _statically_ views the object, i.e. what the C# compiler will let you do with it at compile-time. At run-time it is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OfType<T>` function.

```
...
var lo = new List<object> {new A(), new A()};
var cast = lo.OfType<A>().ToArray();
...
```